# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. " and connectionString

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

I have a web service WCF and I would like retrieve data from Jquery.

But success return null in msg :

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: 'http://localhost:52768/Service1/Statistic_1',
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function (msg) {
    response = msg.Items;
    console.log(msg);

    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        allstat1[i] = [response[i].Geografisch_zone];
    }
    fillDataTable(allstat1);
 },
  error: function (e) {
    alert("error loading statistic 1");
 }
 });
 }
```

I used the debug and it catches an exception in my Statistic_1 method at SqlConnection:

```
public static List<Statistic_1> Helper_Statistic_1()
    {
        List<Statistic_1> result = new List<Statistic_1>();
        Statistic_1 stat1 = null;

        int yearstart = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-4).Year;
        int yearend = DateTime.Today.Year;//2014
        string lastGeographischZone = null;

        string query = "SELECT Year ...";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Context.db.Connection.ConnectionString))
        {
                ...
   }
```

Here is web.config :

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="RMS_DatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=RMS_Database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="16384"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />  
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
 </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: would you be more specific about your question? where is the issue? and what is not required?

Comment: I would like retrieve data of my Statistic_1 method in $.ajax. But success return null value and I get an exception in my Statistic_1 method at SqlConnection... Why?

Comment: “Object reference not set to an instance of an object.” ocured when some object is null and you tried to access that object's property so first confirmed from where this error occurred.

Comment: I don't understand why I have an exception at SqlConnection.

Comment: use this ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RMS_DatabaseConnectionString"].ToString()

Comment: The problem is that when I test the method with WCFTestClient, it works well.

Comment: @DhavalPatel I have to change using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Context.db.Connection.ConnectionString)) in using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RMS_DatabaseConnectionString"].ToString()))?

Comment: I changed but I have always the exception.

Comment: put your code in dropbox and give me link.

Comment: I don't have dropbox, have you got an email?

Comment: erdhavalpatel@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem is somewhere in `Context.db.Connection.ConnectionString`. Check it during debugging.

Instead, try to use what @dhaval-patel suggested in his second comment to get propper connection string: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RMS_DatabaseConnectionString"].ToString()`

(You will need add corresponding namespace to use ConfigurationManager: `using System.Configuration;`)